# OpenCV: Segmentation Fault with destroyAllWindows()

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing a program which displays a video, and when the user presses the 'q' key on their keyboard it displays that frame and records 4 of the user's clicks on the image. However, when I have clicked the 4 points, it randomly throws a Segmentation Fault. I have narrowed the issue down to the `cv2.destroyAllWindows` line in `calibrate.py`. Any help/improvements would be really helpful!

Software details:

- Python 3.9.2
- Raspbian 64-bit OS
- OpenCV version 4.6.0.66

test.py

```
import cv2
import calibrate

path = "crowd.mp4"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        continue

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480), cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow("output", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q' or 'Q'):
        calibrate.main(frame)
        break
        cv2.destroyWindow("output")

cap.release()
```

calibrate.py

```
import cv2


cnt = 0

def click_event(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global cnt

    if cnt == 4:
        cv2.destroyWindow("image")
        return None

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cnt += 1
        #cv2.circle(img, (x,y), (0,0,255), 5, -1)
        print(x,y)


def main(img):

    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: your code does not contain any calls to `destroyAllWindows`. you should be extremely careful in destroying any windows **from inside of an event handler** -- [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: i tried to replace the ```destroyAllWindows``` with ```destroyWindow("image")```, but I am getting the same segfault

Comment: ultimately, OpenCV is a computer vision library, not a GUI library. use a proper GUI library, or work _within_ what OpenCV offers in terms of GUI. **do not** destroy the window in the event handler for that same window.

Comment: okay, i understood what youre saying. But is there any way i can know that the counter has reached 4 and I need to exit main()?

Comment: uh yes, it's a global variable, so check it in the main loop. or set a different flag (global variable) from the event handler that you check in the main loop, to cause actions there.